# How to change default picture in picture gravity?

Tags: android, xml, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I am implementing picture in picture feature for an Android app, and I would like to change default position when the picture in picture opens by default is:

`<!-- The default gravity for the picture-in-picture window.        Currently, this maps to Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT --> <integer name="config_defaultPictureInPictureGravity">0x55</integer> +`

this information is from config.xml in the source code,for example whatsapp change it to another position when you play a video in the chat, but i am trying to figure out the way to override the config.xml file

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a way to do this?